# Trying to apply tuple as args in C++14

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I'm trying to use the apply method as found in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3658.html to apply a tuple of args to a callable.

Here's my code:

```
struct add1_op {
  void operator()(float& dst, float x) const {
    dst = x + 1;
  }
};
struct add_op {
  void operator()(float& dst, float x0, float x1) const {
    dst = x0 + x1;
  }
};

template<class Op>
void f()
{
  float src0[] = {1,2,3};
  float dst[3];

  // my real code has variadic-template parameter packs here
  auto args = std::tuple_cat(std::tuple<float&>(dst[0]),
                             std::tuple<float>(src0[0]));
  apply(Op{}, args);
}

void g()
{
  f<add1_op>();
}
```

and I'm using this `apply` from the above paper:

```
template<typename F, typename Tuple, size_t... I>
auto
apply_(F&& f, Tuple&& args, std::index_sequence<I...>)
  -> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(args))...))
{
  return std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(args))...);
}

// Apply a tuple as individual args to a function
// see: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3658.html
template<typename F, typename Tuple,
         typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>>
auto
apply(F&& f, Tuple&& args)
  -> decltype(apply_(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(args), Indices()))
{
  return apply_(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(args), Indices());
}
```

but clang gives me this error:

```
apply.cxx:48:3: error: no matching function for call to 'apply'
  apply(Op{}, args);
  ^~~~~
apply.cxx:53:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'f<add1_op>'
      requested here
  f<add1_op>();
  ^
apply.cxx:23:1: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with F = add1_op,
      Tuple = std::__1::tuple<float &, float> &]: implicit instantiation of undefined
      template 'std::__1::tuple_size<std::__1::tuple<float &, float> &>'
apply(F&& f, Tuple&& args)
^
```

It certainly looks like I have a tuple of `float&, float` and that's what my add1_op's `operator()` takes. So I'm not sure why it's a substitution failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass an lvalue `tuple` to `apply`, `Tuple` will deduce to an lvalue reference type - and `std::tuple_size` doesn't accept reference types. You therefore need to strip reference-ness from `Tuple` before passing it to `tuple_size`:

```
template<typename F, typename Tuple,
         typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<
             std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>::value>>
auto
apply(F&& f, Tuple&& args)
  -> decltype(apply_(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(args), Indices()))
{
  return apply_(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(args), Indices());
}
```

The fact that the suggested implementation in n3658 doesn't do so is an error.